# CAShapeLayer keeps closing path, I want the path open

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I'm using CA to draw line segments from an array of points. For some reason, although I did not close the NSBezierPath, CAShapeLayer results in a closed shape. The following are my codes. Do anyone else have this problem?

```
// mappedPoints is an array of CGPoints

NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

[path appendBezierPathWithPoints:mappedPoints count:numPoints];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [color CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;

[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: Is the `CGPath` property on `NSBezierPath` in your code? I don't recall that `NSBezierPath` has such a property, and I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm allowing myself to guess here that the `[path CGPath]` call is what's closing that path for you, as that's exactly what happened to me.

To give a bit more context - Apple's [Creating a CGPathRef From an NSBezierPath Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-SW2) sample code, which creates an `NSBezierPath` category method like `CGPath` above, has this in it:

```
// Be sure the path is closed or Quartz may not do valid hit detection.
if (!didClosePath)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

The reasoning behind that (from the same source):

> Quartz requires paths to be closed in order to do hit detection on the
>   path’s fill area

If you're not interested in fill-area hit detection, it's safe to skip over that path-closing part and you'd get the expected behavior.